# Google Places api vs Google Maps search

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have successfully used Google Places Api and was able to retrieve business establishments (shops) given a latlongbound and a keyword. But I cant stop wondering why it returns lesser shops than when you go to maps.google.com and type the keyword. Google Places does not even return those with a name and icon drawn on the map itself.

I want to retrieve a json with a similar result when typing a keyword on maps.google.com and I don't really mind if Google Places is not used.

Comment: Please provide an example of a Places API request you have used and what results are not returned.

Comment: Did you find out why Places API returns such different results to Google Maps search? Tried nearbySearch() and textSearch() with a combination of request arguments and still get nowhere near the number of results as shown on Google Maps web search.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have additional filtering preventing you from querying all the results. Make sure you aren't restricting the 'bounds' or 'region' around your lat/long.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Good luck!